# Fetching JSON, appending to array: Escaping closure captures mutating 'self' parameter

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have prepared [a simple test project at Github](https://github.com/afarber/ios-questions/tree/master/FetchJson4) to demo my problem:

[image: Xcode screenshot]

I have a SwiftUI List and I try to display the `var items:[String]` in it.

When I only have a hardcoded array like below - it works fine and displays in iPhone:

```
items = (1...200).map { number in "Item \(number)" }
```

But when I try to fetch JSON web page and append results to `items` then I get the error:

> Escaping closure captures mutating 'self' parameter

I understand that the line `items.append(str)` modifies the parent ContentView object out of dataTask closure and that is not good for some reason... but how to fix my code then?

```
import SwiftUI

struct TopResponse: Codable {
    let data: [Top]
}

struct Top: Codable {
    let uid: Int
    let elo: Int
    let given: String
    let photo: String?
    let motto: String?
    let avg_score: Double?
    let avg_time: String?
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var items:[String];

    init() {
        items = (1...200).map { number in "Item \(number)" }
        
        let url = URL(string: "https://slova.de/ws/top")!
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {
            data, response, error in
            
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            guard let data = data else { return }
            do {
                let tops = try decoder.decode(TopResponse.self, from: data)
                for (index, top) in tops.data.enumerated() {
                    let str = "\(index + 1): \(top.given)"
                    items.append(str) // this results in compile error!
                }
            } catch {
                print("Error while parsing: \(error)")
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }

    var body: some View {
        List(items, id: \.self) { item in
            Text(item)
        }
    }
}
```

Should I move the `items` out of the View maybe?

My final target is to have the JSON data in Core Data and then update/notify the List from it.

I have such an app in Android (structured as MVVM) and now I am trying to port it to SwiftUI, being a Swift newbie.

**UPDATE:**

I have added [a view model file](https://github.com/afarber/ios-questions/tree/master/FetchJson4) as suggested by achu (thanks!) and it kind of works, but the List is only updated with new items when I drag at it. And there is a warning

> [SwiftUI] Publishing changes from background threads is not allowed; make sure to publish values from the main thread (via operators like receive(on:)) on model updates.

Comment: When modifying the array you are actually modifying the struct, but a struct is a value object so you can' do that. You should have a class that manages the data and not have that code inside your view struct.

Comment: This SO question + answer will help understand the issue.

Comment: Don't misuse a SwiftUI view as a *controller*. Load the data in an extra  `ObservableObject` class and `publish` the stuff

Comment: Here's a tutorial I did on how to do this in SwiftUI: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h42OHc5CRBQ .. although I would recommend learning to use Combine approach instead: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fdxFp5vU6MQ&t=0s. Here's another on MVVM to get you in a better direction https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wEf1YS4vyW8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will move the `items` to ViewModel and eventually move the service call to an APIManager class

EDIT:  The UI update should be in the main thread. Added service call on `ViewModel` `init()`.

```
struct TestView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = TestViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        List(viewModel.items, id: \.self) { item in
            Text(item)
        }
    }
}

class TestViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var items: [String] = []

    init() {
        self.fetchData()
       
    }
    
    func fetchData() {
        let url = URL(string: "https://slova.de/ws/top")!
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {
            data, response, error in
            
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            guard let data = data else { return }
            do {
                let tops = try decoder.decode(TopResponse.self, from: data)
                for (index, top) in tops.data.enumerated() {
                    let str = "\(index + 1): \(top.given)"
                    self.updateItems(str)
                }
            } catch {
                print("Error while parsing: \(error)")
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }

    func updateItems(_ str: String) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.items.append(str)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it almost works - please see my updated question

Comment: Updated the code. you have to call the webservice method on the init and the UI changes should be in main thread

Comment: I removed `items = (1...200).map { number in "Item \(number)" }`  else it will append to this items. you can add it if you want it in your items array